# Sharepoint Reports on Mac

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs

When trying to view Sharepoint Reports, Mac users get the error "An unexpected error occurred while connecting to the report server. Verify that the report server is available and configured for SharePoint integrated mode."

We tried both Safari and Firefox, and get the same error. On the Firefox end, I tried enabling NTLM Authentication, but that did not work. Can Sharepoint reports work on Mac?